DotCMS upgrade from old local version 2.5.1 to dockerized 23.01
Good morning guys, i'm having trouble finding a detailed guide to upgrade an old version 2.5.1 dotCMS to a modern dockerized one 23.01. Actually we are using an Oracle db, which is going through a schema conversion and migration to Postgresql because 23.01 actually needs it. In order to do this we are going through an intermediate version, the 21.06 (latest compatible with oracle). The question is... how can i actually upgrade my old application installed locally to a more modern one like the 21.06 if that seems to be dockerized only? how can i upgrade to that importing all the confs and personalizations? what are the best and more straightforward options?
Thank you guys in advance!
i tried to find a local version for the 21.06 but on the official site seems like there is only the docker image tag of that, anyway i need to switch on docker for the latest version that i need (23.01)

As 2.5 is more than 10 years old at this point and way out of any support, we don't have specific documentation on how to migrate from that to any modern version (21.06 is already out of support and 23.01 will be as of Nov. 2024 btw).  We do have this document that talks about major changes in version to version and what to expect there:
https://www.dotcms.com/docs/latest/upgrading-important-changes
It does not capture all the changes/pitfalls you might encounter but it does talk about the big ones.
Finally, if you are looking for a "distribution" like folder structure, you can just run docker copy and copy the /srv/dotserver folder from any dotcms docker image and that should give you the tomcat directory in which dotcms lives.
